# How to selectively store attributes in Redis when using Spring Session

Tags: spring, session, redis, tomcat8, spring-session

Using Redis with Spring Session, is there any possibility to "select" which attributes to be stored and updated in Redis and filter out the others?
Something similar to "sessionAttributeFilter" or "sessionAttributeNameFilter" properties. For example, sessionAttributeFilter is used by the [memcached session manager](https://github.com/magro/memcached-session-manager) for the same purpose.

Comment: Maybe it's an uncorrect approach. If you can add your own serializer for Redis can you filter data through if?

Comment: Something like this but with your filter in serializer/deserializer https://gist.github.com/thomasdarimont/9a252f4d8d6914d8d559

Comment: But it seems to me that this should have something to do with the Session Manager, etc. The serializer/deserializer is expected to be used **after** it is actually decided whether to store or retrieve some attribute locally or to/from Redis. This is what I expect for attribute selection.

Comment: I understood, will search for desicion

Comment: As summary I can say that I didn't met an oppotunity to set filter on session attributes (worked with Spting Session + Hazelcast)